# File overwriting/reading advice required

Tags: java, io

recently have gone to test a form of key validation code from files in Java. I'm still new to this(IO) and looking online brings endless methods of approaching this but I'm not capable of distinguishing the various pros & cons between these methods. I would like to present my code and ask me how I should tackle in properly, it works but I'm not all too satisfied.

I know most of you are against advice-oriented questions and if it is the case I'll gladly put the topic down, just wanted to ask for some help beforehand. Thank you

```
/*
* To be able to give you a rundown of the situation:
* Inside my project file I have a .txt file named 'MasterKey'
* Initially inside this file is a key and validation boolean 'false'
* On start-up the program analyzes this file, if it detecs a key it then
* Asks the user to input the key. If it is valid it then creates/overwrites the
* Previous file with a new .txt with same name but only "true" is inside it.
* If the key is incorrect, it will continue requesting for the key
*/
import java.io.*;
import java.util.Scanner;
public class MasterKeyValidationTest {
private static Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
public static void main(String[] args) {
    getFileInfo(); //Method below
}
private static void getFileInfo(){
    File readFile = new File("/Users/Juxhin's Lab/Desktop/Projects/MasterKey.txt"); //My file directory
    try{
        BufferedReader getInfo = new BufferedReader(
                new FileReader(readFile));
        String fileInfo = getInfo.readLine(); //Gets the key or 'true'
            if(fileInfo.contains("true")){ //If file contains 'true', program is valid
                System.out.println("Valid");
            }else{
                System.out.println("Enter Key");
                String key = input.next(); //Receive input for the key
                if(!fileInfo.contains(key)) { //If the file doesn't contain the key you just entered
                     System.out.println("Invalid key");
                    key = input.next(); //Receive another key input
                    getFileInfo(); //Start the method from top again to check
                }
                if (fileInfo.contains(key)) { //If the file contains the key you just entered
                    System.out.println("Program valid");
                    FileWriter fstream = new FileWriter("/Users/Juxhin's Lab/Desktop/Projects/MasterKey.txt"); //Create/Overwrite the MasterKey.txt file
                    BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(fstream);
                    out.write("true"); //Input "true" inside the new file
                    out.close(); //Close the stream
                }
            }

    }catch(FileNotFoundException e){
        System.out.println("File not found");
        System.exit(0);
    }catch(IOException e){
        System.out.println("An IO Error");
        System.exit(0);
    }
}
```

}

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is a request for a code review.

Comment: Yes I know and wasn't going to post it in the first place but really needed some advice from you guys. Sorry

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some advice ..

```
1. String fileInfo = getInfo.readLine(); //Gets the key or 'true' .. reads only 1 line (if that is what you want..)

2. use fileInfo =fileInfo.trim() // to remove leading and trailing whitespaces.

3. If you just want to "read" the file, use FileReader, BufferedReader. If you want to "parse" the file, use a Scanner.
```

Comment: Alright thanks man, as for 3rd point, I simply want to read the contents of the file. In that case it's still optimal to use .trim()?

Comment: Its not optimal. But its suggested to do so.. While reading a file you could get unwanted characters, whitespaces. using trim() will save you from reading that garbage

Comment: Alright thanks for the help, just the type of comment I needed